Importing in inline "string" module with Vite
I making kind of in-browser JS code editor app so I have an input field for code.
After every change event I want to eval the code in this input field.
Since the code is in ES format I can't use eval() and have to use import():
// This is the code from input
let inputCode = `
    console.log('Hello World!');
`;

// Transforming it into inline ES module
let inlineModule = `data:text/javascript,` + inputCode;

// Importing our inline module
import(inlineModule).then(module => {});

The above code works just fine.
The thing is, I want to give access to my own package called bitran-parser in this inline module.
So I expect this code to work too:
let inputCode = `
    import { Product } from 'bitran-parser';
    console.log(Product);
`;

// ...

But I get an error saying that path to bitran-parser is incorrect. Changing it to something like /@fs/D:/projects/bitran/packages/parser/dist/index.js does not help, I get the following error: "Failed to resolve module specifier "...". Invalid relative url or base scheme isn't hierarchical.
So my question is, with what should I replace bitran-parser package name so the code work correctly both in Vite's dev and build modes?
Maybe somehow preload my package directly inside Vue App and specify its direct name instead of Vite's manual chunking strategy?

Figured out to solve this using Vite Virtual Modules.
First, we create virtual module plugin.
This plugin also builds our virtual module into separate chunk when we build Vite app:
import { type Plugin } from "vite";

export default function() {
    const moduleName = 'local-bitran-parser';
    let serveMode = false;

    return <Plugin> {
        name: moduleName,
        configResolved(config) {
            serveMode = config.command === 'serve';
        },
        resolveId(id) {
            if (id === moduleName)
                return moduleName;
        },
        load(id) {
            if (id === moduleName)
                return 'export * from "bitran-parser"'; // This is the contents of our virtual module
        },
        buildStart() {
            if (!serveMode)
                this.emitFile({
                    type: 'chunk',
                    fileName: 'parser.js', // Saving our virutal module into file when building the App
                    id: moduleName,
                    preserveSignature: 'exports-only'
                })
        }
    }
}

Now we can use virtual module in inline modules inside App.
For that we need to scan for every import and replace the name of our package with path to virtual module (in dev mode) or path to saved chunk (in build mode):
// ... somewhere inside App

let inputCode = `
    import { Product } from 'bitran-parser';
    console.log(Product);
`;

// Replace import targets when importing from "bitran-parser"
// In `dev` mode: "bitran-parser" --> "https://.../@id/local-bitran-parser" (our virtual module id)
// In `build` mode: "bitran-parser" --> "https://.../parser.js"
function replaceImports(configStr: string)
{
    return configStr.replace(/(import\s+(?:{[^{}]+}|.*?)\s*(?:from)?)\s*['"](.*?)['"]|import\(.*?\)/g, (match, begin, target) =>
    {
        if (target === 'bitran-parser')
            target = location.origin + (import.meta.env.MODE === 'development' ? '/@id/local-bitran-parser' : '/parser.js');

        return begin + ' ' + `"${target}"`;
    })
}

// Executing the code
import('data:text/javascript;base64,' + btoa(replaceImports(inputCode)).then(module => {});

